# How do you create 3 adjustable divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want:

```
  |   A   | |   B   | |   C   |
           ^         ^
```

When you move the `handles` left and right `A`, `B`, and `C` resize accordingly

```
  | A | |   B      | |    C   |
```

What I have is the `||` between `B` and `C` sliding, but not resizing `B` and all I get on the other one is the resize cursor.  Basically `C` is a curtain and covers `A` and `B`.  I did get min size working for `C`.

```
  |   A  |           C        |
```

I broke somebody else's perfectly good code to get this far:

```js
var isResizing = false,
    who='',
    lastDownX = 0;

$(function () {
    var container = $('#container'),
        left = $('#left'),
        right = $('#right'),
        middle = $('#middle'),
        hand2 = $('#hand2'),
        handle = $('#handle');

    handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
        isResizing = true;
        who=e.target.id;
        lastDownX = e.clientX;
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        var temp, min;
        // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
        if (!isResizing) 
            return;
        min=container.width() * 0.1;
        temp = container.width() - (e.clientX - container.offset().left);
        if (temp < min)
            temp = min;
     if (who == 'handle')
            right.css('width', temp);
     if (who == 'hand2')
            left.css('width', temp);
    }).on('mouseup', function (e) {
        // stop resizing
        isResizing = false;
    });
});
```

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* Disable selection so it doesn't get annoying when dragging. */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#container #left {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}
#container #middle {
    margin-left: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}
#container #right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.90);
}
#container #handle {
    position: absolute;
    left: -4px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 80px;
    cursor: w-resize;
}
#container #hand2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 39%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 80px;
    cursor: w-resize;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <!-- Left side -->

    <div id="left"> This is the left side's content!</div>
        <!-- middle -->
    <div id="middle"> 
        <div id="hand2"></div> This is the middle content!
    </div>

    <!-- Right side -->
    <div id="right">
        <!-- Actual resize handle -->
        <div id="handle"></div> This is the right side's content!
    </div>

</div>
```

Been playing with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ju9zb1he/5/

Comment: [This may come in handy](http://gridster.net/demos/resize-limits.html)

Comment: You need a specific solution or a plugin is welcome?

Comment: Not a plugin, I need to generalize the solution and gain enough insight to do so

Comment: I think the css flexbox property might help. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was looking for a solution that required less extensive CSS. It does have one minor bug(**FIXED**), but hopefully this should get you started. Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/9cjjhask/).

Also I aimed to use [DOM Traversal methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) like [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) that way it wouldn't be so attribute dependent, and would be easily reusable if you needed a feature like this multiple times on a page.

**Edit - Further Explanation**

The idea here is `onClick` of a `.handle` we want to gather the total width (var tWidth) of the `.prev()` and `.next()` divs relative to the `.handle` in the DOM. We can then use the start mouse position (var sPos) to substract the amount of pixels we've moved our mouse (e.pageX). Doing so gives us the correct width that the `.prev()` div should have on `mousemove`. To get the width of the `.next()` div we need only to subtract the width of the `.prev()` div from the total width (var tWidth) that we stored `onClick` of the `.handle`. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions, however I will likely be unavailable till tomorrow.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="l-handle" class="handle"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="r-handle" class="handle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left, #middle, #right {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#l-handle, #r-handle {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000;
    width: 2px;
    min-height: 200px;
    cursor: col-resize;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var isDragging = false,
    cWidth = $('.container').width(),
    sPos,
    handle,
    tWidth;
$('#left, #middle, #right').width((cWidth / 3) - 7); // Set the initial width of content sections

$('.handle').on('mousedown', function(e){
    isDragging = true;
    sPos = e.pageX;
    handle = $(this);
    tWidth = handle.prev().width() + handle.next().width();
});

$(window).on('mouseup', function(e){
    isDragging = false;
});

$('.container').on('mousemove', function(e){
    if(isDragging){ // Added an additional condition here below
        var cPos = sPos - e.pageX;
        handle.prev().width((tWidth / 2) - cPos); // This was part of the bug...
        handle.next().width(tWidth - handle.prev().width());
        // Added an update to sPos here below
    }
});
```

**Edit**

The bug was caused by 2 things.

1) On mousemove we were dividing the total width by two, instead of an updated mouse offset.

2) The sPos was not updating on mousemove, and stayed a static number based off of the click location.

**Resolution**

Update the sPos on mousemove that way the mouse offset is accurately based off of the previous mousemove position, rather than the click position. When this is done we can then subtract the .next() div's width from the total width. Then we subtract our current mouse position from the remaining width. The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/9cjjhask/) has been updated as well.

```
$('.container').on('mousemove', function(e){
    var cPos = sPos - e.pageX;
    if(isDragging && ((tWidth - handle.next().width()) - cPos) <= tWidth){
        handle.prev().width((tWidth - handle.next().width()) - cPos);
        handle.next().width(tWidth - handle.prev().width());
        sPos = e.pageX;
    }
});
```

**Edit**

Added an additional condition on mousemove to prevent the drag from exceeding the total width (var tWidth).

Comment: Not to be ungrateful, but a little bit of explanation would help here

Comment: Thats not ungrateful at all! Sure let me edit and see if I can explain a little bit further in-depth.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Answer updated to explain a bit more.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: It seems context is singular, is that the "bug"?   I am trying to understand context per handle

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The bug I experienced was an offset in handle placement, on any click after the first click. I will take another look at the script shortly to see if I can identify it's cause. Is this solution headed in the right direction, or am I way off base?

Comment: It is heading correctly, I do not have enough info to understand the bug

Comment: Click and adjust the left handle. Then click the right handle, you will see it jump 40-50 pixels offset from the mouse position. This is the bug I am referring to.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by context, but I can't see how to fix it

Comment: Okay good, we are on the same page haha. I haven't had much chance to look into it yet, but I should here in the next few minutes. Maybe at that time we could move this to chat and take a look together?

Comment: I fixed the bug. I will update the answer with an explanation. Give me just a few minutes.

Comment: Edited. I hope that explanation covers it. Let me know if that doesn't make sense or if you have any other questions!

Comment: Awesome! The only problem I found happens when you push the left handle entirely to the right one... Some minor flickering happens (the last container goes down just for a few millisecs).

Comment: This could likely be fixed by adding a max-width to the container. Looking now.

Comment: @Armfoot I put in an additional condition to prevent it from exceeding the total width. Good eye, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Have you had a chance to mess around with this yet? How did this work out for you?

Answer (score -1):

Can you please explain what you're trying to accomplish?

I don't believe you need to use position: absolute. The premise of absolute positioning is to override the margin and padding imposed on an element by its parent.

You don't need to do this, all elements have relative positioning by default which makes them push eachother around and don't allow overlapping.

I'm probably missing something, but I think this is what you want with nothing but some very basic CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/3bdoazpk/

```
<div class='first'>
    asdf
</div><div class='second'>
    dasdf
</div><div class='third'>
    sadf
</div>

body {
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.first, .third {
    width: 40%;
}

.first {
    background-color: red;
}

.second {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 20%;
}

.third {
    background-color: green;
}
```